# Failed to enable unit: File foo.service: Bad message

Tags: systemd

I have a simple unit file:

```
[Unit
Description=do magic foo

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

If I try to enable it, I receive this message:

```
root@server# systemctl enable foo
Failed to enable unit: File foo.service: Bad message
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There is a typo in the unit file. The closing `]` on the first line was missing.

I added the char and now it works.